# how to format commit message for some people in git hook?

Tags: git, format, hook, commit

people should add bug ID in commit message in some format,such as [BUG33] [review leader=...] ...
and not every committer must have to follow this formula,i mean scm can write free in commit message.
i have searched that commit-msg hook may help to implement it.
any one can git me some similar hook examples

Answer (score 0):

The book progit has an excellent example of these, both server-side and client-side. You can find [a few examples here.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) One example taken from that link and adapted to your commit message would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$refname = ARGV[0]
$oldrev  = ARGV[1]
$newrev  = ARGV[2]
$user    = ENV['USER']

puts "Enforcing Policies... \n(#{$refname}) (#{$oldrev[0,6]}) (#{$newrev[0,6]})"
$regex = /\[BUG: (\d+)\]/

# enforced custom commit message format
def check_message_format
  missed_revs = `git rev-list #{$oldrev}..#{$newrev}`.split("\n")
  missed_revs.each do |rev|
    message = `git cat-file commit #{rev} | sed '1,/^$/d'`
    if !$regex.match(message)
      puts "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly"
      exit 1
    end
  end
end
check_message_format
```

This should reject any commit whose message isn't formatted with the string "BUG:" followed by a number (presumably from your issue tracking system).

Comment: hi Christopher,how can make the client-side hook in version control.i mean i have to create commit-msg hook file for all local repositories if the hook is not in version control.i tried to use ln -s ../../.hooks/commit-msg commit-msg.but failed!

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't have any trouble at all with a symlinked hook a few minutes ago. Are you sure you're using the right name / syntax? As for how to version control the hooks, I recommend using a wholly different repository (perhaps even called "hooks" or "ops" or something else) and then linking what you want out of it. It's a personal preference though. You could also put it in your "main repository" with the rest of your code.