# How can I insert and retrieve a custom field into a .gitconfig file?

Tags: git

I have the following .gitconfig:

```
[user]
name = name
email = email@email.com
custom_field = AAA
```

Getting name and email is easy using `git config`.

How can I get the value of custom_field :

```
$ git config --global user.custom_field 
error: invalid key: user.custom_field
```

Answer (score 10):

Your command is failing because you've put an underscore in the custom field's name. To add a custom field to the `.gitconfig` file, use this command:

```
git config --global user.customfield <value>
```

You can then retrieve it with:

```
git config --global user.customfield
```

For example:

```
$ git config --global user.customfield test
$ git config --global user.customfield
test
```

Also, avoid `_`'s in the custom field name. Git doesn't parse them:

```
$ git config user.custom_field test
error: invalid key: user.custom_field
```

Comment: Thanks but that's retrieving it on the local side. I need to get it in a hook on the server

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish specifically? When you say "getting name and email is easy using git's builtin commands", to what are you referring?

Comment: If the .gitconfig file you're talking about it local, but you're trying to access that data server-side, you're out of luck. You could, however, enforce a commit message template: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3967136/877115 and then reject commits without `custom_field` server-side: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11314667/877115