# How do I to require an issue in the commit for git check in?

Tags: git, jenkins, issue-tracking

Is there an issue tracker that integrates with git (not github) that requires an issue in the commit message? Or is there another recommend way to keep track of story velocity used by developer managers?

Optimally, I want the users on my development team to only check in code attached to an issue (that hopefully belongs to them) so I can keep track of sprint's story velocity.

Edit:
Found a suitable solution for JIRA (https://github.com/joyjit/git-jira-hook). I would like a full open source product so a similar solution for bugzilla or another issue tracker would be great.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but for one approach check out [`git hooks`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), and [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312760/how-to-format-commit-message-for-some-people-in-git-hook). You'd probably have to parse your issue-tracker issues and ensure that the `issue-id` appears in the `commit-message` using the `git pre-commit hook`.

Comment: Looking nows. Thanks.